# Pure Javascript data Post

Tags: javascript, xml

I need to post/send some XML from one web page to my server. How could I do this?

And, yes, I do need to do this using nothing but pure Javascript.

Any suggestions?

Comment: They do make your life easier but they also overload your pages and increase the overall loading time. I don't recommend using JQuery unless your project heavily depends on it.

Comment: can we add the tag 'life_before_sarissa'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

function getXMLHttpRequest()  {
    var activeXVersions =  ["Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0","Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0","Msxml2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];

    try {
        return new XMLHttpRequest;
    } catch (e) {
        for (var i=0; i < activeXVersions.length; i++) {
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject(activeXVersions[i]);
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function callAjax(url) {
    xhr.open(“POST”, url, true);
    var xmlContents = document.getElementById(‘xml′).value; // xml contents

    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleAjaxResponse;
    xhr.setRequestHeader(“Content-type”, “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”);
    xhr.send (‘xml=’ + xmlContents  );
}

function handleAjaxResponse() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            alert( xhr.responseXML);
        } else {
            alert (‘An error occurred: ‘ + myRequest.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this 1 of two ways.

1. Use XHR
2. Use an iframe

The first option is the modern way, and the preferred way these days.

My suggestion is to use a library like jQuery, which will make this a trivial matter using  `$.post`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe to be a good tutorial for learning AJAX [link](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp)

(Note: AJAX means Asynchronous JavaScript and XML and is pure Javascript.)